# Whether binary operations are closed or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, binary-operations

I recently studying Gallian Abstract Algebra 8th edition by Pearson Book. And found an exercise of chapter "group" that asks to find binary operations which are closed.

But by the definition of binary operations $*:G\times G \to G $ is essentially closed because the definition says "Let G be a set.A binary operation on G is a function that assigns each ordered pair of elements of G an element of G".
If the question be "which of following operations are closed ?", that is a better question.
Am I right about the definition or I interpret in wrongly?

Comment: Well, context matters.  What does the exercise ask, exactly?  What definition does that book provide for a binary operation?  There are reasonable contexts in which one can speak about a failure of closure.  For instance, the irrational real numbers are not closed under addition.

Comment: Which edition of the book? Exercise 2 in which section? You should keep this question as self-contained as possible.

Comment: Post edit:  note that the author switched from "binary operation" to simply "operation".  Thus, for instance, the addition of two irrational real numbers is a perfectly well defined real number, it just isn't forced to be irrational.  Look at the given examples, I expect you'll find things like that.

Comment: I have the 8th edition of this book.Perhaps in new edition it is changed to only operation.